# Gitlab post-receive hook doesn't work

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am using custom_hooks for project on gitlab which hosted locally on my server. Here is a code(i want to deploy code to specific folder, on every commit to repository):

```
#!/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby
# Fix the PATH so that gitlab-shell can find git-upload-pack and friends.
ENV['PATH'] = '/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:' + ENV['PATH']
#!/usr/bin/env ruby


# This file was placed here by GitLab. It makes sure that your pushed commits
# will be processed properly.


# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "

# 2. Only deploy if master branch was pushed
if (branch =~ /master$/) == nil
    # puts "Received branch #{branch}, not deploying."
    exit
end

# 3. Copy files to deploy directory
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('/etc/*specific folder*')
`GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master`
# puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"

# 4.TODO: Deployment Tasks
# i.e.: Run Puppet Apply, Restart Daemons, etc
```

What i have done already :

1)Changed custom_hooks owner to git

2)Changed post-receive file owner to git and made it executable

3)Changed dest. folder owner to git, and give 777 permission for this folder

But, when i am trying to commit, nothing happend